# testing-library/react failed tsx file in concourse pipeline

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest, babel-jest, testing-library, concourse-pipeline

For some reason, my tests are running fine locally, but failed during concourse CI pipeline test. I compared `npx jest --showConfg` with local setup, I don't see the difference that will cause the issue. It is strange that the other `.tsx` tests are running fine, only the tests that have `import` below statements failed. I did research on `jest.config.js`, `tsconfig.json`, `setupTests.js`, `babel.config.js`, `Dockerfile`, `package.json`, and `package-lock.json` files... but still haven't figured out what is missing. Any ideas? Thanks!

Below is the import statement that I used in those failed tests files.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
```

I am getting the error below in concourse pipeline:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
```

jest configure output:

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "/tmp/jest_0",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "cwd": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code",
      "dependencyExtractor": null,
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "detectOpenHandles": false,
      "errorOnDeprecated": false,
      "filter": null,
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globalSetup": null,
      "globalTeardown": null,
      "globals": {},
      "haste": {
        "computeSha1": false,
        "providesModuleNodeModules": [],
        "throwOnModuleCollision": false
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "node"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": [
        [
          "MsalAuthService",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/test/MsalAuthServiceMock.js"
        ],
        [
          "AuthService",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/test/authServiceMock.js"
        ],
        [
          "GraphService",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/test/authServiceMock.js"
        ],
        [
          "ErrorReportingService",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/test/ErrorReportingServiceMock.js"
        ],
        [
          "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/test/fileMock.js"
        ],
        [
          "\\.(css|less|scss)$",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/test/styleMock.js"
        ]
      ],
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "cbdb51e30f6e73bcd3a3c5be677e9e95",
      "prettierPath": "prettier",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "resolver": null,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code",
      "roots": [
        "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
        "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/src/setupTests.ts"
      ],
      "skipFilter": false,
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testRegex": [
        "/test/.*.(test|spec).(tsx|ts)$"
      ],
      "testRunner": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          "^.+\\.tsx?$",
          "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": 0,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": null,
    "coverageDirectory": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": null,
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "detectOpenHandles": false,
    "errorOnDeprecated": false,
    "expand": false,
    "filter": null,
    "globalSetup": null,
    "globalTeardown": null,
    "json": false,
    "listTests": false,
    "maxConcurrency": 5,
    "maxWorkers": 15,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "failure-change",
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "projects": null,
    "rootDir": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "skipFilter": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "testSequencer": "/tmp/build/f541ec31/source-code/node_modules/@jest/test-sequencer/build/index.js",
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": null,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "24.9.0"
}
```